# The selected dataset in Public data set in BigQuery is not pinned many time. How to get pinned?

Tags: google-bigquery

Using BigQuery, when I select a public data set the same is not pinned in explorer side.

Comment: BigQuery only supports pin projects

Comment: if pin/unpin functionality for any object in Navigator is important for you - you can try Goliath (BigQuery IDE) from [Potens.io Suite](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/potens-io/potensio) of BigQuery centric productivity Tools